# Fatal error: Call to undefined method DateTime::add()

Tags: php, datetime

```
<?php
function OtherDAY($start,$total){

    $date = new DateTime("$start");
    $date->add(new DateInterval('P'.$total.'D'));
    $finish=$date->format('Y-m-d');
    return $finish;

}

$start=date("Y-m-d");
$otherday=OtherDAY("$start",'15');
die($otherday);`
?>`
```

It is showing me "not a date format" after i kill it, **how to fix this**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
$date = new DateTime("$start");
```

To

```
$date = new DateTime($start);
```

And

```
$otherday=OtherDAY("$start",'15');
```

To

```
$otherday=OtherDAY($start,'15');
```

You are not passing the value of the variable in, as you are passing it in as a string